Why would the theoretical pH not match the measured pH when performing a titration of NH4OH with HCl?
I ran a weak base - strong acid titration experiment using an automatic titrator. I started with an aqueous ammonia stock solution (somewhere in the range of 0.1 - 2.5 wt.%) that was left open to atmosphere overnight to allow ammonia to evaporate (wanted to see the difference between sealed and open).
From there 10 mL of that ammonia solution (titrand volume) was diluted with 90 mL of DI water. I measured the starting pH of the ammonia solution as 10.64. I then titrated the solution using 1.0 N hydrochloric acid to determine the concentration of ammonia. The titrant volume at equivalence was 2.125 mL using the 1.0 N HCl.
I used the equilibrium base constant equation to calculate the theoretical concentration of hydroxide ions and from there a theoretical pH of 11.2. Work shown below:


Why would my theoretical pH be higher then my empirically measured pH?

One of reasons is your theoretical pH prediction worked with approximation that molar concentrations are numerically equal to thermodynamic activity. // You did not provide the volume of titrated ammonia solution (not ammonium hydroxide solution, as hydroxide neutralises ammonium).

The substance NH4OH does not exist. It is a solution of ammonia NH3
in water. Nevertheless many people believe it exists. This opinion is justified by an old theory built in the 19th century. Please read the following published report to be convinced about this fact. Maurice Cosandey, Why we are all using a non-existent compound : NH4OH. CHIMIA, 2021, 75, No 7/8, p. 679 - 680.

@Poutnik I think a much bigger error would come from dissolved CO2 in the sample - this probably trumps any activity issues, which would only start to appear at such low concentrations.

In any case, I don't understand the downvote - while the OP might want to explain a bit more about what steps he did (both in the titration and the calculation), it is a good question about what limits the accuracy of titration and is definitely not trivial.

Well, due CO2,  the activity coefficients would get even lower.

Sorry for my ignorance but I don't come from a chemistry background. I have edited the OP to include calculations and additional titration information. Given that during titration after the dilution I expect a concentration of ammonia around 0.1 wt. %, do you think ion activity will affect the results enough to account for the pH difference observed? Is dissolved CO2 a common occurrence in commercially purchased ammonia solutions?

@NicholasKam I don't think the concentration is big enough for activity coefficients to be significantly different from one. (Only if you wanted quite precise calculations.) CO2 dissolves in any water that is left open to the air and the dissolution is accelerated in bases due to formation of HCO3$^-$ and CO3$^{2-}$.

@Poutnik I have no idea why you keep talking about activity coefficients... The main effect is that dissolved CO2 will radically change the pH to be more acidic. (E.g. this is the reason why if you leave a pink phenolphthalein solution after titration to stand, it will slowly turn colourless.)

@FusRoDah My prior comments were not aware of later edit, involving explicit exposure to air.  I do not deny the major CO2 influence. The comments pointed out the fact measured pH rarely fits calculated ones and CO2 absorption creates ionic strength forming ammonium and (hydrogen)carbonate.

I think the main effect is CO2 dissolved in the sample. When you titrate the solution with HCl, you not only titrate the NH3, but also the HCO3$^-$ and CO3$^{2-}$ ions present in the solution. This means that more HCl is needed to reach equivalence than would be expected.
If you convert that value back to the concentration of ammonia, you then get a bigger value than expected.
A quantitative calculation of this effect would also have to consider the kinetics of CO2 dissolution (and the inverse process), since it is quite slow (i.e. we can't just use equlibrium constants).
The solutions you are using are quite dilute, so can probably be considered ideal within experimental error. Activity coefficients start to be significant for ions in concentrations more than $10^{-3}$M, but the effect of CO2 is probably much bigger than the departure from ideality. If you wanted, you could try to use the Debye-Hückel law to estimate the activities in the equilibrium constants and see how they change.

There is a mistake about the volume of the solution whose pH is to be measured. In the beginning, Nicholas starts from a solution called Stock. $10$ mL of stock is pipetted into a beaker, and $90$ mL water is added. This produces a diluted solution whose measured pH was $10.64$. This diluted solution was titrated by $2.125$ mL $\ce{HCl}$ $1$ M, containing $2.125$ millimol $\ce{HCl}$. So the diluted solution contained $2.125$ millimole $\ce{NH3}$.
As a consequence, the concentration of $\ce{NH3}$ in the diluted solution, in mole/L,  is $\ce{\frac{2.125·10^{-3}}{0.1}}$ = $0.02125$ M. This is ten times smaller than the result obtained by Nicholas.
From the definition of $K_{\mathrm{b}}$, [OH-] can be calculated, using the technical approach used by Nicholas
$\ce{[OH-]}$ = $\ce√K_{\mathrm{b}}$· [NH3]$   =  \ce{√1.75 10^{-5} · 0.02125}$ = $6.098· 10^{-4}$
pOH = - log$\ce{[OH-]}$ = $3.2148$
pH = $14$ - pOH = $14 - 3.2148  =  10.78$
This final value is not extremely different from the measured value $10.64$. The difference may be due to the use of concentrations instead of activities in the calculations.
